# What do I do about mold on my sourdough starter?

Tags: sourdough, mold

I started my mother yesterday at 6:00am. with 2 tsp salt and 2 tbsp honey, 4 cups potato water, 4 cups unbleached natural wheat flour. I was told to wait two to three days. Well, 24 hours later I lifted my wicker top and the thing was absolutely frothing. I told my wife 2 hours later to check it and she said there was some green mold on it, but it smelled okay. Reading some of the question responses, it looks like I can scrape it off and put the mother in the fridge overnight. Is that true?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just scrape the mold (I suspect due to the honey in the recipe) off and continue as normal providing there was only a little bit of mold on the surface.

If there was quite a lot or you're unsure about it then you could discard most of it then use just a tablespoon or two of the mother to seed another starter. Then if after 1 or 2 'feedings' it smells yeasty and is frothing nicely then it should be perfectly fine to use.